# Can you use a Bluetooth headset to receive Skype calls?

Tags: bluetooth, skype

I have a Lumia 920 running the Black update, and a Plantronics bluetooth headset. I can make calls (either normal voice, or via Skype) and talk and listen through the headset.  However, all incoming calls don't go to the headset - audio only comes from the phone's speakers.

This is rather aggravating, as whenever somebody calls me on Skype I can't hear them through the headset. Is this a limitation of Skype on Windows Phone 8, or limited to particular headsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a headset limitation, I use creative headsets and it works fine I can make calls, answer call and even redial the last number or Skype contact I had a call with.
And all calls go through my headsets nothing rings on my phone.
If you can try another headsets from a different brand and check if the problem persist

Comment: Are you using that with a 920 or a different phone?  Is that on 8.0 or 8.1?

Comment: With 1520 on WP8.